# MethodError while running VGG19 model in Flux (Julia)

Tags: julia, vgg-net, flux.jl

The below mentioned code is taken from [model-zoo](https://github.com/FluxML/model-zoo/blob/master/vision/cifar10/cifar10.jl). I am trying to run the [vgg19 tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-side-by-side-julia-v-s-python-5ac0645587f6) in julia using flux library.

**Code:**

```
#model
using Flux
vgg19() = Chain(            
    Conv((3, 3), 3 => 64, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 64 => 64, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 64 => 128, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 128 => 128, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 128 => 256, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 256 => 256, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 256 => 256, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 256 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    BatchNorm(512),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    flatten,
    Dense(512, 4096, relu),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4096, 4096, relu),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4096, 10),
    softmax
)

#data

using MLDatasets: CIFAR10
using Flux: onehotbatch
# Data comes pre-normalized in Julia
trainX, trainY = CIFAR10.traindata(Float64)
testX, testY = CIFAR10.testdata(Float64)
# One hot encode labels
trainY = onehotbatch(trainY, 0:9)
testY = onehotbatch(testY, 0:9)

#training

using Flux: crossentropy, @epochs
using Flux.Data: DataLoader
model = vgg19()
opt = Momentum(.001, .9)
loss(x, y) = crossentropy(model(x), y)
data = DataLoader(trainX, trainY, batchsize=64)
@epochs 100 Flux.train!(loss, params(model), data, opt)
```

When I execute this file on IJulia, the following error is thrown:

```
MethodError: no method matching ∇maxpool(::Array{Float32,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::PoolDims{2,(2, 2),(2, 2),(0, 0, 0, 0),(1, 1)})
Closest candidates are:
  ∇maxpool(::AbstractArray{T,N}, !Matched::AbstractArray{T,N}, !Matched::AbstractArray{T,N}, ::PoolDims; kwargs...) where {T, N}
```

Please suggest some solution for this error and if possible do provide a brief explanation or reference.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The complaint is that you have a mix of Float32 and Float64, which even if this worked would be a performance disaster. I presume the problem is `CIFAR10.traindata(Float64)`, and that `Float32` there would improve things.

Comment: Thanks @mcabbott for the suggestion, it works fluently!!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @mcabbott, the issue was related to the input type of the data. This can be fixed by changing the `type` from `Float64` to `Float32` for below mentioned parameters under `#data` section.

```
trainX, trainY = CIFAR10.traindata(Float32)
testX, testY = CIFAR10.testdata(Float32)
```